# Vertical Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of questions regarding my current vertical menu. My first question is regarding the placing of my menu. My screen is too small for me to see if my changes have worked or not, but I want it so the vertical menu does not separate from the main content. The actual site that I am working on can be found at www.mecostaosceolacourts.org. That is the current live version that has not been changed. The code that I am specifically talking about can be found below and has been changed to hopefully solve my problem:

```
/*Side Menu Bar*/
#wrapper {
padding-left: 0;
/*remove the following
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
*/
}

/*remove

#wrapper.toggled {
padding-left: 250px;
}
*/

#sidebar-wrapper {
z-index: 1000;
position: fixed;
left: 250px;
width: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-left: -250px;
overflow-y: auto;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
/*remove the following
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
*/
}

/*remove

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
width: 100%;
padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
margin-right: -250px;
}

*/
```

Where I've said "remove" is the code I believe taking out would alleviate my problem.

My second question regards to adding submenu's to the specific code. I've tried left and right I feel like to add submenu's and the code seems to not want to have it. Is there something that I am missing?

I've only posted one other question on here, so I hope I'm doing it right and not stepping on toes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know why you commented out the transition, do you know what [transitions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) are?

Comment: I did not want to remove the code in case I could not remember it. I took the code from an example and just modified it to fit what I wanted it to look like. So if I need part of the code that I commented out I did not want it to be lost.